# Any ways to damping metallic snap fastener domes afterwards?

Tags: material-selection, sewing, metal, restoration, fasteners

I bought  handmade cushion covers, but what I did not realize to expect was that at the back, they're closed with a row of half an inch wide snap fasteners, and their metallic dome backs protrude.

[image: Metal snap]

On a typical fabric sofa, this would probably not be a problem, but I meant them for an armchair with quite sensitive faux leather upholstering on the arm rests, and I'm afraid that the metallic caps could end up scratching or even breaking the puffy but relatively thin and elastic leather.

Is there anything that I could do about this without having to consider removing the snap fasteners completely?

Comment: Perhaps a stupid question, but: Can you turn the cushions to have the fasteners on the front and consider them a decorative element? Won't work if the original front is decorated and meant to be seen, of course.

Comment: @Stephie No. The whole point of the design is the front fabric, and then the metallic domes would be uncomfortable for the people leaning against the cushions.

Comment: The snaps don't look pointed or like they have sharp edges, You could always test them on an unseen part of your chair to see if they damage the faux leather.

Comment: @abbie Not doing anything does not really answer my question...

Comment: Hi user158589, "pretesting" your project is not considered doing nothing.  Most crafters/sewers/modelers, etc., consider it an essential step in knowing if something works for the purpose or not, whether/how it can be modified, etc.  Until you test to see if the snaps damage your delicate faux-leather, you don't know if you have a problem.  Additionally, being polite to people trying to help you goes a long way around here.  Good luck and let us know everything turns out.

Comment: I would think about painting the back with rubber-cement (aka rubber).  When it dries, it is .. rubber.  Rubber is compliant, elastic, and non-scratchy.  Rubber cement, as long as it is applied to the button and not the cloth, is not likely to soak through.  I might put something more like a silky polymer on top of the rubber cement, so that there is "lubricity".  Leather, btw, tends to be pretty resilient.  What does the part that is likely to scratch look like?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest concealment. Take a strip of very fine leather and sitch it over the line of metal domes. You might be able to find a cloth that would do the same, but the combination of suppleness and toughness needed would be hard to find in a woven product.